# Every C# console application prints "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: c#, .net

Every time I run a C# console application (either from Visual C# Express 2010 or Visual Studio Ultimate 2010), the first line of output is

> The system cannot find the path specified

, even when my program doesn't do anything, and doesn't specify any paths. Why would this happen? Is there some way to check what the path it's looking for might be? Programs run fine otherwise. I tried to catch a System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException but couldn't figure out where to put the try/catch blocks.

I am running Windows 7 x64, building console applications, and have tried all the different platform targets (x86, x64, AnyCPU) I can in Visual Studio, always getting the same

I have been having some other issues and have a hunch this may have something to do with those, which is why I am trying to figure it out. Thanks!

Below is z .csproj file that Visual Studio generated (this project displays the problematic behavior I am describing when run from the command line or when run from VS)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{04EC9A5E-74D8-4A5F-BCD3-05D9B6CA1477}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>UsingNLOpt</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>UsingNLOpt</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Client</TargetFrameworkProfile>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>false</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

---

**EDIT**: Solved - an Autorun entry to an nonexistent directory in the registry for the Microsoft Console. See the answer below.

Comment: What happens if you just run cmd from the start menu? Same thing?

Comment: What's the code you are running? And your stacktrace?

Comment: Well worded question but not a programming problem. Sounds like a very curious problem. All I can suggest is the very weak reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: I'd argue that a problem when debugging a console application from within Visual Studio really is a programming problem, to be honest.

Comment: Open your project properties to see if you have some pre/post build events set up in your project file. Try compiling your project/solution using msbuild from command line, if it is happening from there too, it seems either you have pre-post build event set up. OR there is some other target which is causing this. Looking in your csproj file/files is the way this can be investigated and fixed.

Comment: What happens if you build the application and then run it direct from cmd, rather than from VS?

Comment: Running cmd from the start menu does the same thing. "cannot find the path specified". There are no pre-build or post-build events set up in the C# project settings. Building and running from the command line does the same thing. I will edit my original question to add a .csproj file. Perhaps it is something in there. I didn't post any code as this happens on every project I run, even 'empty' ones

Comment: Is the problem occurring only with .NET console apps you've built, or every console app you run? Can you replicate the problem on another machine?

Comment: Thanks. Solved in the other answer below. A strange registry entry was causing it

Comment: @Rory- please don't update the title to read "SOLVED". Simply accept the answer that solved your problem (I appreciate that you can't do that without waiting a while).

Comment: @razlebe Thanks for the heads up. Will do so from now on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you check your registry:

```
\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
```

in both the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and HKEY_CURRENT_USER hives?

It may be that the command processor is trying to run something on startup that isn't there.

Comment: You got it. Thank you. There was an Autorun entry in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER that doesn't exist. It was to a drive letter (H:) that's never been on my system and that I couldn't read/have typed. I assume something wrote to the registry when installing..

Comment: Excellent. Not a problem that I've encountered before, but it sounded suspiciously like that. Feel free to click the Accept button, as I'm a "rep whore" today ;-)